# merge multiple ffmpeg commands into one line to make the whole process faster

Tags: unix, video, ffmpeg

I want to merge multiple commands into one so that whole processing time would be fastest. What I am doing so far is

1. A video file is uploaded from a webform and and server upload into a temp directory.

   ```
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$param]['tmp_name'], $filePath)) {


          return $filePath;
        }
   ```
2. add black borders around the video(through ffmpeg command) - video uploads again to a directory

   ```
   $command_new = "ffmpeg -i $filePath -vf 'scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1' $video_file";
       exec($command_new);
   ```
3. optimizing the video(ffmpeg command) - video uploads again to a directory

   ```
     $cmd_new = "ffmpeg -i $video_file -c:v libx264 -crf 28 $optimizeResultFile";
   ```
4. merging the uploaded file with the existing video file present in the database into one and uploading that file into directory(through ffmpeg command)

   ```
          $command_new = "ffmpeg -i $optimizeResultFile   -i $second_video_path   -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]'   -map [vid]   -c:v libx264   -crf 23   -preset veryfast $videomerge";
   ```
5. //add custom sound in that final merged video

   ```
          $cmd_new = "ffmpeg -i $videomerge -i $audio -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 $with_new_audio";
   ```

Is it possible to do all at one command and not in multiple commands. This process takes 1 min to upload a final file. want to make it faster

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i $database -i $uploaded -i $audio -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:-1:-1,setsar=1[right];[0:v][right]hstack,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 2:a -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast -c:a copy -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- The [hstack filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) is used instead of pad + overlay.
- This assumes `$database` is the same height as `$uploaded`.
- This assumes `$audio` is AAC. Otherwise, change `-c:a copy` to `-c:a aac`.